# How to resize the background image of an element to fit the full screen with css?

Tags: html, css, background

I've been working on a website for someone and I'm having some trouble;

I'm trying to make the background image of a  fit the size of the screen that it's being displayed on.

On the [live site](http://fadehq.com/), I'm using `height:100vh;`, which is fine and dandy on my screen no matter how big or small I make my browser window, but on a 4k monitor it doesn't resize to fit the screen.

If anyone has any idea on how to fix this, please do tell, as I can't figure it out.

Thanks,

Jesse

Answer (score 1):

If you want the background to strech then you need to use

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work: https://gyazo.com/00b3722fea1b1ae0b7824af77db629c0

Comment: Sorry to keep on commenting, but I believe I've fixed it by using background-size: cover; and height: 100vh;, but I'm waiting to see if it works on a 4k monitor.

Comment: You need to add it to the ".chome" class. I've inspect elemented your website and it works fine. Stretch it across 10 monitors and it will still behave the same way. Might look dreadful but it does what you want it to. See this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/3Ylz3Cj.jpg.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so very much with your help <3